# Scheduling task on remote computer via command line

Tags: networking, server, scheduled-tasks

I just want to make sure i'm doing the right thing.

I want to run a script which distributes software silently, as system account, with maximum rights. The CALLFILE.bat contains the full command to install the software package from a server path, ex.: \\server2\script_to_install_software.cmd

Here is what I have, does it make sense or am I missing something?

1-Create task:

```
SCHTASKS /create  /S COMPUTERNAME  /tn "TESTTASK" /tr "\\SERVER1\c$\temp\CALLFILE.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 2030/01/01 /ST 01:00 /RU SYSTEM /RL HIGHEST
```

2-Run it:

```
SCHTASKS /run /S COMPUTERNAME /tn "TESTTASK"
```

3-After it runs successfully, delete it:

```
SCHTASKS /Delete  /S COMPUTERNAME /TN "TESTTASK" /f
```

As always thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You don't need the `/RL HIGHEST` option. A task that uses the SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, or NETWORK SERVICE account runs with system integrity.

Comment: You're creating the task in the root folder. You may want to use a subfolder named for your organization/project, e.g. `"Contoso\TestTask"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I create it as a user for example DOMAINE\USER1 , i then have to  specify /RL HIGHEST right?

Comment: For a non-system user, set the password via `/RP *` (prompted) if you want to run in the services session, i.e. "whether user is logged on or not". That should be enough to get the highest runlevel for an administrator. `/RL HIGHEST` is required to force an interactive task to be elevated.